# Why should non-POD types in C++ be opaque to C clients?

Tags: c++, c

gcc 4.4.4 c89

I was just reading [a discussion at DevX](http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?t=170263) about calling C++ code from C since I have to do something similar. I am just wondering what user Vijayan meant by "[make sure that non POD types in C++ are opaque to C clients.](http://forums.devx.com/showpost.php?s=db615835edf59a51363fce84407da786&p=513431&postcount=6)"

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Do you know what a POD type is?

Comment: @Rob. Yes, I forgot. Edited my answer with the link.

Comment: @James, This is the first I have heard of a POD type.

Comment: @ant2009: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c. "Opaque" means that C code isn't capable of validly manipulating the contents of an object that isn't of POD-type, because non-POD-types might have "C++ magic" going on in their structures that C doesn't know about and will trip over. Also, the definition of a non-POD type won't compile as C anyway, so the C client couldn't include the header even if it wanted to do something.

Comment: But then, even the definition of POD structs may fail to compile on C. Having a POD struct is by no means a guarantee you may include its definition into a C file.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: The definition of opaque types I'm familiar with is a type that's only declared, not defined (`struct Foo;`) and which therefore is manipulated via pointers only (`struct Foo* create(); void dispose(struct Foo*);`. Obviously, it wouldn't be legal C if you wrote `void dispose(Foo*);`, there's more to source compatibility than just the type definition itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a type to be opaque means you can't look inside it: it's a "black box" that can be passed around but not inspected or manipulated directly by the C code.  You typically refer to the object using either heap-allocated memory and void*s, or using functions to determine the necessary length and buffers.

For example, a C++ object might contain a `std::string`, but the layout of a `std::string` is not specified in the C++ Standard, so you can't write C code that directly reads from or writes to the string (at least, not without having a total understanding of the `std::string` layout, manually revalidated every time the compiler/STL is updated).

So, to allow C code to access the object, you might write C-callable functions such as:

```
#if __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void*       object_new();
const char* object_get_string(void* p_object);
void        object_set_string(void* p_object, const char* s);
void        object_delete();
#if _cplusplus
}
#endif
```

With C++ implementation ala:

```
class Object { std::string string_; ... }
void* object_new() { return new Object; }
const char* object_get_string(void* p) { return ((Object*)p)->string_.c_str()); }
...
```

Here, the object_XXX functions provide the C code with a safe way to use the Object.

Answer (score 3):

C can only deal with POD types.

Consequently, you cannot pass objects of non-POD types to C programs (by value). Also, if you pass pointers of non-POD types to C programs, they can't interact with the objects pointed to.

Answer (score 3):

POD = Plain old data structure = C structs, no virtual methods, etc. You need to write wrapper functions for C to access non-POD types (i.e., classes).

More on POD:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure

Answer (score 2):

Making the type opaque means, as per the line in the link:

```
typedef struct base base ; /* opaque */
```

makes the name of the handle available to C code, but not the definition of the type. This means that the C code cannot access any members directly, but has to go through the interface functions.

Note that you do not have to make a cast to a generic , i.e. void*, pointer, although doing so is one option, as per 9dan's answer.

Note that such a style of interface is in my experience a very nice way to manage encapsulation even in pure C code, just as in the standard C streams library.

Answer (score 1):

Making opaque to clients means nothing special. C stream file I/O (`FILE* f = fopen`) API is the typical example that present opaque handle to clients.

Apparently C can not handle non-POD type so you must hide C++ implementation from C clients but provide access method.

Example:

### C++ Implementation

```
class MyLibrary {
MyLibrary();
~MyLibrary();
int DoSomething();
...
}
```

### Declaration for C clients

```
typedef void* OPAQUEHANDLE;

extern OPAQUEHANDLE MyLibrary_OpenLibrary();
extern void MyLibrary_CloseLibrary(OPAQUEHANDLE h);
extern int MyLibrary_DoSometing(OPAQUEHANDLE h);
```

### Implementation for C clients (in .cpp file)

```
extern OPAQUEHANDLE MyLibrary_OpenLibrary()
{
    return new MyLibrary;
}

extern void MyLibrary_CloseLibrary(OPAQUEHANDLE h)
{
    delete (MyLibrary*) h;
}

extern int MyLibrary_DoSometing(OPAQUEHANDLE h)
{
    return ((MyLibrary*)h)->DoSomething();
}
```